# hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualize'

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am running the scikit-image Histogram of Gradients [example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html)

The example code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, color, exposure


image = color.rgb2gray(data.astronaut())

fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax1.set_title('Input image')
ax1.set_adjustable('box-forced')

# Rescale histogram for better display
hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0, 0.02))

ax2.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(hog_image_rescaled, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.set_title('Histogram of Oriented Gradients')
ax1.set_adjustable('box-forced')
plt.show()
```

Put simply, it does not work and reports the following error:

```
    fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True)
TypeError: hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualize'
```

I can view the astronaut image by commenting out the above section, so that is not the problem.  Does anyone know why it is failing?

Comment: What version of `scikit-image` are you using?

Comment: scikit-image==0.13.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a very small error but the spelling for your keyword argument `visualize` is wrong. It should be

```
fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True)
```

Refer [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html#hog) for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  The sckit-image website is wrong.  For posterity : https://web.archive.org/web/20171001204310/http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html

Comment: The docs aren't wrong---they're just for a different version of skimage than you are using, where the issue has been fixed.  The argument was originally named `visualise`, is now `visualize`, but both are accepted for the next two versions until we can deprecate `visualise` through our standard deprecation cycle.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt: Now only `visualize` is accepted, the other form returns `hog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'visualise'`

Comment: That's correct, @mins ­— as mentioned in the above comment, we went through a deprecation cycle. See the 0.16 release notes: https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/release_notes_and_installation.html#api-changes